# Orthogonal product and scalar product

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there somebody who knows how to proof that the scalar product of two vectors $u$ and $v$ is equal to the product of the orthogonal projection of $u$ and $v$? For all $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^3$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider two vectors $ \vec u $ and $ \vec v $ inclined towards each other at an angle $ (\vec u,\vec v)$ w.r.t. each other (connected by their tails of course).

$ Now,$

$ \vec u \bullet \vec v =|\vec u||\vec v| \cos(\vec u,\vec v)$

Also, now resolve $ \vec u$ parallel to $ \vec v$ and perpendicular to $ \vec v$

$ Component \ of \ \vec u \ parallel \ to \ \vec v \ \implies  u_{parallel}= |\vec u \cos(\vec u,\vec v)|$

So,

$ \vec u \bullet \vec v =|\vec u||\vec v| \cos(\vec u,\vec v) =|\vec v||\vec u \cos(\vec u,\vec v)| = u_{parallel}|\vec v| $

Comment: @Sander If you like it, upvote it